# NodeJS websocket access second layer JSON Data

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, websocket

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=instrument:XBTUSD');


ws.on('message', function incoming(a) {
  p=JSON.parse(a)
  console.log(Object.keys(p));
  console.log(p.data);


});
```

code can be tried here - [npm.runkit.com/ws](https://npm.runkit.com/ws)

I am trying to access the subparameters of the JSON object like bidprice and ask price. However unable to go beyond the data level. Have tried using data[0].bidprice,data.bidprice but nothing works. 
Not sure if p.data is returning a str instead of a JSON.

Sample data is as follows

```
{ table: 'instrument',
  action: 'update',
  data: 
   [ { symbol: 'XBTUSD',
       lastPrice: 6686,
       lastTickDirection: 'MinusTick',
       lastChangePcnt: 0.0053,
       timestamp: '2018-09-23T15:04:18.946Z' } ] }
```

if output is stored as var a, a.data works but a.data.symbol or a.data[0].symbol doesnt work

Comment: have edited the question

Comment: That sample dosn't contain the stuff your trying to capture!

Comment: for simplicity i have removed the rest. But we try to access lastPrice here